# regex Don't match the word after this one

Tags: php, regex, curl

I'm programming a tool that tell you which is the country of the IP but I have problem

This is the code that I tried

```
<?


$ip = "109.224.62.197";


$curl = curl_init();

CURL_SETOPT($curl,CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.ipligence.com/geolocation");

CURL_SETOPT($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"ip=".$ip);

CURL_SETOPT($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,True);

CURL_SETOPT($curl,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,True);

$exec = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

$regex = "/Country: (.*)[^(<br>)]/";

if(preg_match($regex,$exec,$result)){

print_r($result);

}

?>
```

And this is the result that I got

```
Array ( [0] => Country: Iraq
Continent: Middle East
Time Zone: GMT+3  more demo?'; [1] => Iraq
Continent: Middle East
Time Zone: GMT+3  more demo?'; )
```

But I want only to match the country name Iraq and after that I don't want to display anything else

Comment: Please post a sample of what the _raw response_ looks like in `$exec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why doesn't your regex work?

Your regular expression is as follows:

```
/Country: (.*)[^(<br>)]/
```

This will not work as you expect. `(.*)` is a greedy match and will consume as many characters as possible, eating until the end of the line.

`[^(<br>)]` is a negated character class, but it doesn't mean: "*Match everything that's not a `<br/>`*". It means: "*Match anything that's not in the list of characters `( < b r > )`*".

### How can it be fixed?

You can simply your regex as follows:

```
/Country: ([\w ]+)<br>/
```

**Explanation:**

- `/` - starting delimiter
- `Country` - match the character sequence `Country` case-sensitively
- `[\w+ ]+`  - match any word character (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) or a literal space character one or more times
- `<br>` - match the character sequence `<br>`
- `/` - ending delimiter

The `preg_match()`  statement would look like:

```
if (preg_match('//Country: ([\w ]+)<br>//', $exec, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches);
}
```

Comment: What if the country is `United Arab Emirates`?

Comment: can you explain for us what did you write so we can understand better why (\S+) I saw an other question he used ([^<]*) what is the difference?

Comment: That's not fixed.  It still won't match a country with spaces in its name.

Comment: @AlanMoore: Not sure if `[\w ]` is the best way to write it, but it [seems to work](http://regex101.com/r/uP1fG1).